# Poblar Spinner desde SQL

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

Hola necesito cargar un `Spinner` con los datos provenientes de mi Base de Datos (SQL). Para ello tengo creada una clase con un id y una descripción. El problema es que en lugar de mostrar la descripción, en el `Spinner` se me muestra el nombre del Paquete.
Dejo el código por las dudas. Muchas Gracias.

```
private void poblarSpinnerObra(ArrayList<ObrasCuenta> list) {
    ArrayAdapter<ObrasCuenta> adapter =
            new ArrayAdapter<ObrasCuenta>(MejorasFragment.this.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

    spinnerObraMej.setAdapter(adapter);

    spinnerObraMej.setOnItemSelectedListener(
            new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
                    if ((pos!=0) && (id!=0)) {
                        // buscar comprobantes adeudados
                        Object item = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);
                        idSubsistema = ((ObrasCuenta) item).getIdObra();
                        buscarDeuda();
                        cargarRecyclerView();
                    }
                }
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {}
            });
}
```

Con el código anterior (sacado de Internet) busco de poblar el Spinner con un ArrayList pero se me visualiza de la siguiente manera. El comportamiento en el evento es el deseado. Aclaro por si sirve de algo que los datos se encuentran en un Fragment
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola @DavidC, la opción más sencilla para esto es sobrescribir el método  toString() de tu objeto ObrasCuenta, revisa mi respuesta, saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias @Jorgesys .! el método toString() solucionó todo. Recién hoy volví a trabajar por eso la demora de la rta. Abrazo

Comment: Excelente David, saludos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que se esta imprimiendo la representación de un objeto ya que estas usando un `ArrayAdapter` de objetos tipo `ObrasCuenta` :

```
 ArrayAdapter<ObrasCuenta>
```

Tienes dos opciones, crear un Adapter personalizado o esta opción que es la más sencilla,

simplemente sobrescribe el método `toString()` de tu objeto `ObrasCuenta` retornando la variable que contiene la descripción

```
   @Override
    public String toString() {
        return description;
    }
```

de esta forma en lugar de obtener esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

obtendras en el Spinner el valor del objeto que deseas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]